# How do I increase room for the queries in general_log?

Tags: logging, mysql

In MySQL, I've set the log_output to FILE, and general_log to ON, and the queries start rushing in for me to debug. BUT, after 1022 bytes, each query is abruptly truncated. How can I increase this limit so that I get to debug also the long queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version on MySql are you using? there was a reported bug similar to this @ http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=21557

Comment: Thank you very much, I was running 5.1.22, and of course the bug is fixed in 5.1.23 ;-)